# Angular directive for horizontal Bootstrap form

Tags: angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a directive for my Angular to help with the integration of form fields. I've implemented Scott Allens solution from his Angular playbook, and it works fine for a normal stacked form.

I need however to adapt it to a horizontal form instead. Here's my code:

**Markup**

```
<div form-group>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="vm.name">
</div>
```

**formGroup directive**

```
function link(scope, element) {
    setupDom(element[0]);
}

function setupDom(element) {
    var label = element.querySelector("label");
    label.classList.add("control-label");

    var input = element.querySelector("input, textarea, select");
    var type = input.getAttribute("type");
    if (type !== "radio" && type !== "checkbox"){
        input.classList.add("form-control");
    }

    element.classList.add("form-group");
}

function formGroup() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: link
    }
}
```

The output becomes:

```
<div form-group="" class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="vm.name" class="form-control">
</div>
```

And that's fine for stacked form. Since I need a horizontal form, my output needs to look like this:

```
<div form-group="" class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label col-sm-3">Name</label>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="vm.name" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried many solutions and I can get it work with single elements like an input, textarea or a select. It becomes much more tricky when I have something like two radio buttons inside my markup like this:

```
<div form-group>
    <label>Active</label>

    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="active" ng-value="true" ng-model="vm.active"> Yes
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="active" ng-value="false" ng-model="vm.active"> No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The desired output of the above mentioned code should be:

```
<div form-group class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Active</label>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="active" ng-value="true" ng-model="vm.active"> Yes
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="active" ng-value="false" ng-model="vm.active"> No
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please notice that the input(s) in the form-group is not fixed. It can be either a single input, textarea, select, a group of radio buttons or checkboxes. I'm lost for how I can make that happen. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I made some small changes to Mark Veenstra's code to make it (sort of) working:

```
function setupDom(element) {
    element.classList.add("form-group");

    var label = element.querySelector("label");
    label.classList.add("control-label", "col-sm-3");

    var input = element.querySelector("input, textarea, select");
    var type = input.getAttribute("type");
    if (type !== "radio" && type !== "checkbox"){
        input.classList.add("form-control");
        angular.element(input).wrap(angular.element('<div class="col-sm-9"></div>'));
    }

    var div_radio = element.querySelector("div[class='radio']");
    angular.element(div_radio).wrap(angular.element('<div class="col-sm-9"></div>'));
}
```

This does not work completely as intended with multiple radio inputs since it only wraps the `<div>` on the first radio input element.

The output from radio button example in my original post using Marks code is:

```
<div form-group="" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Active</label>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="active" ng-value="true" ng-model="vm.active" value="true"> Yes
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="active" ng-value="false" ng-model="vm.active" value="false"> No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SOLUTION**

Check out the Plunker with the final result: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wv6V86hHTCz3URS9DhdU?p=preview

Comment: Can you share a plunker showing your attempt to achieve this? It will then be easier to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: @AbhishekJain check out this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wv6V86hHTCz3URS9DhdU?p=preview) for the final result, if you're interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `angular.element` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) you can find the method `wrap()` to be able to wrap HTML around a selected element. Or see [this](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) direct link.

So what you could do in your directive is change the `setupDom()` function to match your requirements per type of form element.

```
function link(scope, element) {
    setupDom(element[0]);
}

function setupDom(element) {
    element.classList.add("form-group");

    var label = element.querySelector("label");
    label.classList.add("control-label col-sm-3");

    var input = element.querySelector("input, textarea, select");
    var type = input.getAttribute("type");
    if (type !== "radio" && type !== "checkbox"){
        input.classList.add("form-control");
        input.wrap(angular.element('<div class="col-sm-9"></div>'));
    }

    var div_radio = element.querySelectorAll("div[class='radio']");
    div_radio.wrap(angular.element('<div class="col-sm-9"></div>'));
}

function formGroup() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: link
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** This code is not tested, maybe there are some minor mistakes, but I guess you'll get the point now.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @mark. Please take a look at my post below.

Comment: Maybe change `element.querySelector("div[class='radio']")` to `element.querySelectorAll("div[class='radio']")`

Comment: tried it, but it wrapped each radio group in it's own `div`. I updated my original question with the solution and link to a Plunker.

Comment: Looks like you got it working after some tips from me into the right direction. If you could give me some credit it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Mark's suggestion came close, but it didn't solve my problem completely. I ended up using the following code in my formGroup directive:

```
(function (module) {
    "use strict";

    function link(scope, element) {
        setupDom(element[0]);
    }

    function setupDom(element) {
        element.classList.add("form-group");

        var children = angular.element(element).children();
        var labels = children.splice(0, 1);

        // Set label classes
        labels[0].classList.add("control-label", "col-sm-3");

        // Wrap children in div
        angular.element(children).wrapAll(angular.element("<div class='col-sm-9'></div>"));

        // Handle inputs
        var inputs = element.querySelectorAll("input, textarea, select");
        for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
            var input = inputs[i],
                type = input.getAttribute("type");

            if (type !== "radio" && type !== "checkbox") {
                input.classList.add("form-control");
            }
        }
    }

    function formGroup() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: link
        }
    }

    module.directive("formGroup", formGroup);

}(angular.module("app.core")));
```

Check out this Plunker to see it in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wv6V86hHTCz3URS9DhdU?p=preview